# A ring which has many distinct left inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

I'm trying to find a ring which has an element that has many(more than two) distinct left inverses.

I first tried the (square) matrices but then realized that if a matrix is a left unit, then it has determinant greater than 0, thus it is also a right unit and has unique inverse.

And then next I tried to do it with functions with usual addition and composition, and I found this example(in the first answer, by user23211): [Kaplansky's theorem of infinitely many right inverses in monoids?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156238/kaplanskys-theorem-of-infinitely-many-right-inverses-in-monoids)

But I realized that the space of functions does not form a ring since the distribution law fails.

To make distribution law hold, we can only have homomorphisms; while the elements in the above example are not.

I also have seen that we can construct a similar examples with infinite vector spaces, but they are not rings.

Is there any ring like this?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70781/589.

Comment: *I also have seen that we can construct a similar examples with infinite vector spaces, but they are not rings.* Well, I know for sure the most common example (the ring of linear transformations of an infinite dimensional vector space) appears *numerous* times throughout the site. The problem seems to have been that it is hard to find a reference linking this with the 'infinitely-many-left-inverses' observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a countably infinite dimensional vector space $V$ and let $R$ be the endomorphism ring of $V$.

Suppose the vector space has a basis $\{v_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$; define the endomorphism $f$ by
$$
f(v_k)=v_{k+1}
$$
and, for every $v\in V$, the endomorphism $g_v$ by
$$
g_v(v_0)=v,\qquad g_v(v_{k+1})=v_k
$$
Then, for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
g_v(f(v_k))=v_k
$$
so $g_v$ is a left inverse of $f$ in $R$.

---

It is an interesting exercise proving that, if the element $a\in R$ ($R$ any ring) has two distinct left inverses, then it has infinitely many.

Comment: yes, this was what I saw but I somehow misunderstood that the $V$ was the space while they were saying about the endomorphism ring! thank you for stating the example so clearly. and yes as I linked I happened to know about Kplansky's theorem. it was pretty interesting!