# Uniqueness of right-quasi-regular inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I've been thinking about the following exercise that my teacher left:

Let $R$ a ring. An element $a \in R$ is right-quasi-regular if there is $b \in R$ such that
$$a + b+ab = 0.$$
In this case $b$ is said to be the right-quasi-inverse of $a$ (this definition follows from [Herstein's Non-commutative Rings book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Noncommutative_Rings.html?id=hXa7mVyZCzYC&redir_esc=y)). **Then, every right-quasi-inverse of a right-quasi-regular element is unique.**

I can't prove it neither find a counter example. What I can prove is that if $a\in R$ is a right and left-quasi-regular then the left and right-quasi-inverses are the same. Can it help me to solve the exercise? If not, is there any kind of counter-example or solution?

Comment: Does $R$ have an identity?

Comment: @Freddie, not necessarily

Comment: The statement is actually false. As in the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246249/a-ring-which-has-many-distinct-left-inverses), we have $(g_v-1)+(f-1)+(g_v-1)(f-1)=0$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: That is to say, even in rings with identity, rq-inverses are not necessarily unique.

Comment: @Freddie I think that this counter example works! Thank you!